# Proper reeves deadlift/shrug form

Tags: bodybuilding

My question is, how do I keep my torso when doing the reeve's shrug? Should I have vertical or have tilted back?

Answer (score 1):

Deadlifts and shrugs are very different exercises than just happen to involve holding a barbell with the same grip. This equally applies to the Reeves variations.

Shrugs are done with an upright torso, because you're trying to target shoulder elevation (lifting the shoulders up) rather than shoulder retraction (pulling the shoulders back). Deadlifts are done bending forwards, because that's necessary to reach the bar when it's on the ground.

Comment: I feel I have a tendency to lean a bit back when shrugging, natural cue or no?

Comment: Sounds like that could be a weakness of the upper back spinal extensors (typically worked through squats, deadlifts, and rows), where you don't have the strength to hold your back straight when holding the bar, so you're leaning back at the hips instead as a compensatory means of keeping the bar close to your body. But we'd need to actually see it to be sure.